# Dot's pretzels seasoning

Tags: seasoning, pretzels

I made a batch of homemade [Dots pretzels](https://dotspretzels.com/pretzels-brands/) (pretzels with garlic salt, lemon pepper, cayenne pepper, etc.) They turned out to be too salty. My wife thinks that we can keep the same amount of seasonings and pretzels per batch but with double the oil to make them less salty. I say the same amount of oil and pretzels but half the seasonings. Who's correct?

Comment: Just a side note to add that I’m skeptical you can get that magical Dots flavor without some msg, yeast, artificial butter… something!

Answer (score 5):

If you want your pretzels to be less salty then you simply need to add less salt, there's nothing complex about it. Doubling the oil will just make them more oily, it's not going to dilute anything because you're still adding the same amount to the pretzels at the end of the process. If you like the balance of other herbs and spices then just reduce the salt and leave everything else the same.

Comment: Op might want to use salt and garlic powder vs garlic salt to better control the salt